# Wp All in one seo modify description

Tags: wordpress, keyword, meta-tags, meta

In one of my [website](http://pharmadesiccants.com/) under **Dashboard-> All in one Seo -> General Settings-> Home page settings->Home description** I had description up-to **167 characters**.

But in live website, it doesn't shows full description as you can see it using source code of my home page.

I had same description in **Home page->edit->description area.**

How to resolve this issue, any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you are a developer, you can increase the meta description character limit of this plugin. Consider this response from a forum: http://semperfiwebdesign.com/forum/optimizing/description-tag-length/#p2554

To increase the description characters, just open up aioseop.class.php and change line 8:

var $maximum_description_length = 160;

to

var $maximum_description_length = 300;

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Meta description broken with the word counts in All in one SEO plugin follow the below steps,

just open up folder **all-in-one-seo-pack/aioseop.class.php**

find the `home_description` array

change

`'count'    => true,` to `'count'    => false,`